# JavaScript "imagepicker" - All elements selected by default

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, jquery-plugins

The 'Image Picker' Plugin select all my elements as `selected` by default.
But i haven't set such preferences. 
The Web example ([Image Picker Example](http://rvera.github.io/image-picker/)) is simple and easy works fine. When you click on a element it will be `selected`.

But in my case all my option-elements will be `selected`.

Here is the code:

```
 $('.languageList select').imagepicker({
        show_label:true
    });
```

---

```
    <div class="languageList">
                <select multible="multible" class="image-picker" style="display: none;">
                    <option data-img-src="/img/flags/United_Kingdom.png" value="1">United Kingdom</option>
                 </select>

        <ul class="thumbnails image_picker_selector">
            <li>
              <div class="thumbnail selected">
                <img class="image_picker_image" src="/img/flags/United_Kingdom.png">
                  <p>United Kingdom</p>
              </div>
            </li>
        </ul>...
</div>
```

i use this one: [Image Picker](http://rvera.github.io/image-picker/)

Comment: Reproduce this into a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), would really help us out in order to help you.

Comment: @urbz i've try my best and will infom you, when the fiddle is ready

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution by my self. 
The problem was, a typing mistake. Instead of:

```
<select multiple="multiple"...
```

i made a mistake with "multiple" and used "multible".

Edit:
i found an other mistake:
i have create multible `<select><option></option></select>`-pairs in a loop. Then of course, every pair have only 1 entry and this entry was selected.
I think this was the main problem...

i'm sorry, but i hope this will help others with the same problem.